# Running npm init cannot find module

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I am trying to initialise the NPM in my project, but it consistently produces this error:

```
C:\Users\work-\Documents\MyWork\Folder\utils>npm init
npm ERR! code MODULE_NOT_FOUND
npm ERR! Cannot find module './init.js'
npm ERR! Require stack:
npm ERR! - C:\Users\work-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\npm.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\work-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\cli.js
npm ERR! - C:\Users\work-\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\work-\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-18T08_27_55_371Z-debug.log
```

I've tried uninstalling node and reinstalling/restarting my PC, but I still get the same issue.

How can I make NPM init work?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to update npm

npm install npm -g